# DateDiff between current and next row is >= 10 days

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm using MS SQL server. I have the following sample columns and how do I pull the ID's(col. Parentref) where the **CreatedDate** of the current row is greater than or equal to 10 days than next createdDate from its next row (probably Lead row ) ParentRef is unique column and primary key.

Thanks in Advance!

```
NoteID          PARENTREF   CREATEDDATE     CREATEDTIME
3045040          2000363      20160822     165850795
3045127          2000363      20160822     170617138
1843964          2014297      20160216     180154700
2027279          2014297      20160317     171825864
572327           2019109      20150608     65935687
572339           2019109      20150618     70305803
517207           2021908      20150526     163803159
517212           2021908      20150611     163900097
```

Comment: Confirm the datatypes on the `CREATEDDATE` and `CREATEDTIME` columns

Comment: its int and int

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would use `lead()`:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*, lead(createddate) over (order by createddate) as next_createddate
      from t
     ) t
where next_createddate > dateadd(day, 10, createddate);
```

Comment: I get this conversion error/. Tried converting to date but stil the same. Arithmetic overflow error converting expression to data type datetime.

Comment: Okay, I converted to char first and then to date.. it worked... Thanks for your help :)